# Cant get CarType when trying to get from FirebaseDatabse

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm getting the following error when i try to run app when i clear cache of my app it works fine but when i close it and run it again it crashes

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.ggsbusiness.amirmemon.comsatsbusservice.Model.ComsatsDriver.getCarType()' on a null object reference
```

when trying to get current cartype from Firebasedatabse.

```
drivers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Common.driver_tbl).child(Common.currentBusDriver.getCarType());
```

**From the Common.class**

```
public class Common {

    public static final String driver_tbl = "Drivers";
    public static final String user_driver_tbl = "DriversInformation";
    public static final String user_rider_tbl = "RidersInformation";
    public static final String pickup_request_tbl = "PickupRequest";


    public static final String baseURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com";
    public static ComsatsDriver currentBusDriver;

    public static IGoogleAPI getGoogleAPI()
    {
        return RetrofitClient.getClient(baseURL).create(IGoogleAPI.class);
    }
}
```

**And this is the ComsatsDriver.class:**

```
public class ComsatsDriver {
    private String name,phone,carType;

    public ComsatsDriver(){
    }

    public ComsatsDriver(String name, String phone, String carType) {
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.carType = carType;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getCarType() {
        return carType;
    }

    public void setCarType(String carType) {
        this.carType = carType;
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
child(Common.currentBusDriver.getCarType());
```

You are actually getting `getCarType()` of null object which it isn't currently received from the Firebase that's why it shows the null error.

Instead, get the nodes like:

```
drivers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Common.driver_tbl).child("CurrentBusDriverNode"); // Or whatever your json output node is
```

Then loop through the output of the Listener in `onDataChange()` and then you'll be able to get the data.

Check this piece of code of [Firebase sample](https://github.com/jirawatee/FirebaseRealtimeDatabase-Android/blob/2892da63b8fcdba62db694496b9bf2177ca15299/app/src/main/java/com/example/database/PostDetailActivity.java#L62). And then, [the Listener](https://github.com/jirawatee/FirebaseRealtimeDatabase-Android/blob/2892da63b8fcdba62db694496b9bf2177ca15299/app/src/main/java/com/example/database/PostDetailActivity.java#L70).